# Trying to understand python decorators

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn about [Python decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) but am still confused.  I'm trying to solve the following error:
"Create a function to combine two numbers, and then create a decorator that doubles the result."

My code :

```
x=6
y=5
u=None
def multi(func):
    def adding(*args):
        print("Welcome func {}".format(func.__name__))
        func(*args)
    return adding

@multi
def tyu(x,y):
    print("=> ", x+y)
    u = x+y
    return u

u = tyu(x,y)

@multi
def dss(u):
    dd=u*2
    return dd
yy=dss(u)
print("** ", yy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. You just need to return `func` inside your decorator and multiply the result by 2.

```
def multi(func):
    def adding(*args):
        print("Welcome func {}".format(func.__name__))
        return 2 * func(*args)
    return adding

@multi
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Example:

```
In [11]: def multi(func):
    ...:     def adding(*args):
    ...:         print("Welcome func {}".format(func.__name__))
    ...:         return 2 * func(*args)
    ...:     return adding
    ...: 
    ...: @multi
    ...: def add(a, b):
    ...:     return a + b
    ...: 

In [12]: add(3, 4)
Welcome func add
Out[12]: 14
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , almost i spent two days trying to figure it out, time to learn decorate of classes . Thx again